# Constantly getting '...:' instead of 'Out [#]:' in Python 3.7 (Spyder)

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

About 95% of the time I input something into my console (function of something, defined object, etc.) I don't get an output, instead, I get 3 dots, with a colon, as if it wants me to input something.

Often times I can just spam the variable into the console, and eventually instead of '...:', I'll get 'Out [###]:(thing I called)', but this is absolutely ridiculous.

I've never had this problem in 2.7. I've always used Spyder as my IDE.

I've done my research on here, asked around, but cannot solve this.

Thanks in advance :)

Screenshot of my problem
[image: Screenshot of my problem]
[Another shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehgDv.png)

Comment: Are you sure you pressed enter on the last line and there were no newlines ahead?

Comment: @user8408080 You mean, am I sure there are no lines ahead of the last line? (in this picture, the 3rd '...:') I am definitely sure of that. The more times I press enter, the more of these '...:' that appear.

Comment: Nono I mean: Lets say, there are three `...` lines. If your curser is either in line one or two and you press enter, another `...` line will appear. **But** if your curser is in the last (third) line and you press enter, a new prompt should appear

Comment: @user8408080 Oh, I just made sure of that, and my cursor was in the corresponding line, but no luck :/ still another '...'

Comment: @snakecharmerb I do not, I just read through to make sure.

Comment: So in conclusion: You have a completely fresh prompt. You write some code and made sure you have no open parenthesis. You press enter. The code does not get executed, but new `...` line appears. Right?

Comment: @user8408080 That's correct.

Comment: That's some advanced witchcraft which I never heard about. Is this a fresh install?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What operating system are you using?

Comment: @user8408080 It definitely appears to be some advanced witchcraft! It is a fresh install indeed. Like, a couple of days ago. The problem has persisted for basically the entire time (minus the first few hours, if I remember correctly).

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Ah! I probably should've pointed out that this is on my MacBook.  So I guess it's Mojave or whatever OS Macs are running now. This problem has not happened on my desktop PC.

Comment: Please try `conda install ipython=6.5` and `conda install ipykernel=4.10` to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Does this happen with _any_ code, or just some specific?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba How exactly do I do that? Sorry, I'm not a very experienced programmer, mostly code for physics!

Comment: @poke Any code.

Comment: If you're using Anaconda (hopefully you are), then you need to open Terminal.app and run the two commands I mentioned above, one after the other.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I gave it a go, but it seems like it messed with some basic things, like now it's telling me 'No module named 'numpy''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution a couple months ago, I figured I would post it here for those who may be experiencing the same issue. Simply press Shift+Enter instead of just Enter, when inputting into Console. Stupidly simple solution. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0):

The python interpreter is expecting additional lines of code. Either you typed the wrong command or you made a mistake in what you typed. This will happen, for example, if you type part of a command and hit return. The interpreter is expecting the rest of the command.

Comment: Right, but it seems like something weird is causing it to happen, which I'm trying to figure out. For example, if I look in my variable explorer after running my code, and I type one of those variables into the console and press enter, what would the console need more than that? It should just output the variable. Another example is if i type len(P) for a defined variable P, it will still output 3 dots.

Comment: I just posted another picture of what happens sometimes if I enter the variable multiple times; it finally outputs it. So odd

Comment: R is not a valid statement.  its probably looking for R = 20 or something like that.